# Read the values stored in text file separated by comma and display them one by one in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have a text file having three fields category name, image name and link or URL. The three fields are stored in the text file separated by comma. I want to read the textfile values and display them one by one that is in a column format. So all the category names will be displayed in one column, image name in one column and link in one column.

I have read the text file and i get all the contents in text file in a variable. The content that i get in variable is as follows:
glass,glassbowlcategory.jpg,www.google.com glass,glassbowlcategory.jpg,www.google.com glass bowl,images1.jpg,http://www.fitnessfirstusa.com/catalog.asp?Brand=LG%20Sciences

In the above string first one is category name, second is image name and third is link.

I have used the folllowing code to read text file.

```
Sub BuildFileList(strFolder)

    Dim strFileName1

    Dim strSearchText

    Dim objFSO, objTextFile

    Dim strReadLineText

    Dim intLineNumber,strNewContents

    Dim strLineNumbers
    Dim objFile



    ' Name of text file to search:
    '
    'strFileName = "readme.txt"
    strFileName1 = "saveimagename.txt"

    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2


    '' Create an instance of the the File System Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(strFileName1))
    intLineNumber = 0
    '
    strLineNumbers = ""
    Do While Not objTextFile.AtEndOfStream

       intLineNumber = intLineNumber + 1

        strReadLineText = objTextFile.ReadLine

          ' response.Write(strReadLineText)



           strNewContents = strNewContents & strReadLineText & vbCrLf

           response.Write(strNewContents)


    '
    Loop    

end sub
```

Please advise how can i split the contents that i get in the variable and display them

Comment: Step one is getting the code formatted properly. Read the formatting instructions carefully when you create the post. Following instructions is important in programming.

Answer (score 3):

For tabular data

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim objTextFile
Dim intLineNumber, strNewContents, strReadLineText
dim data, columns

strFileName1 = "saveimagename.txt"

Set objTextFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(strFileName1))
intLineNumber = 0
strLineNumbers = ""

data = split(objTextFile.readall(), vbcrlf)
for intLineNumber = 0 to ubound(data)
    columns = split(data(intLineNumber), ",", 3)
    if (ubound(columns) = 2) then
        strNewContents = strNewContents & "<tr><td>" & columns(0) & "</td><td>" & columns(1) & "</td><td>" & columns(2) & "</td></tr>" & vbcrlf
    end if
next

response.write "<table>" & strNewContents & "</table>"
```

Comment: This is masterful, thank you very much for this post. Oh that I can only up vote the once.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you could use Microsoft ActiveX Database Objects (ADO) for that?

here are some links:

[Much ADO about Text Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx)

[Microsoft ODBC Desktop Database Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711711%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

and some sample code:

```
'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx
dim conn : set conn = server.createObject("ADODB.Connection") 
dim rs : set rs = server.createObject("adodb.recordset")
dim sql

conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
      importPath & ";" &_
      "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=" & HDR & ";FMT=Delimited"""

sql = "SELECT * FROM " & myImportFile
rs.open sql, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```